# A better way to restart/reload Gunicorn (via Upstart) after 'git pull'ing my Django projects

Tags: django, nginx, reload, gunicorn, upstart

Im looking for something better than `sudo restart projectname` every time I issue a `git pull origin master`, which pulls down my latest changes to a Django project. This `restart` command, I believe, is related to Upstart, which I use to start/top my Gunicorn server process.

This restart causes a brief outage. Users hitting the web server (nginx) will get a 500, because Gunicorn is still restarting. In fact, it seems to restart instantly, but it takes a few seconds for pages to load.

Any ideas on how to make this seamless? Ideally, I'd like to issue my `git pull` and Gunicorn reloads automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a graceful reload, you should instead use Upstart's `reload` command, e.g.:

```
sudo reload jobname
```

According to the initctl (Upstart) [manpage](http://man.cx/?page=initctl&do%5Bgo%5D=go), `reload` will send a `HUP` signal to the process:

```
reload JOB [KEY=VALUE]...

       Sends the SIGHUP signal to running process of the named JOB instance.
```

...which for Gunicorn will trigger a graceful restart (see [FAQ](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-reload-my-application-in-gunicorn)).

Comment: noob question:  and is `jobname` something I get from the process itself or an option I passed into gunicorn?

Comment: @TheGrimmScientist, `jobname` is the name of your upstart job/config.  E.g. For the upstart job at `/etc/init/foo.conf`, `foo` would be the jobname.

Comment: @Gary Is there any example available?

Comment: @Dewsworld, an example upstart config?  Many examples can be found, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747605/daemon-vs-upstart-for-python-script   For a full reference, see: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Comment: In the context of this question, try `sudo reload /etc/init/gunicorn.conf`. This assumes you've got `gunicorn.conf` at `/etc/init/`.

Answer (score 111):

You can tell Gunicorn to reload gracefully using the `HUP` signal like so:

```
kill -HUP <pid>
```

(see the [FAQ](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-reload-my-application-in-gunicorn) for details)

I use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to control my Gunicorn server, which allows me to use this (slightly hacky) way of reloading Gunicorn after a deploy:

```
supervisorctl status gunicorn | sed "s/.*[pid ]\([0-9]\+\)\,.*/\1/" | xargs kill -HUP
```

You could obviously achieve something similar with `pidof`, or `ps`.

This is actually run from a [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) script, so I don't even have to logon to the server at all.

Comment: with supervisor you can still ask gunicorn to write its pid to a file if you want with [pidfile](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#pidfile) but BE CAREFUL to put it somewhere where the user setup by supervisor to run gunicorn will have the right to write!

Comment: Thanks - that's a neater way of doing it!

Comment: actually, the [pidfile setting](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=pidfile) is only supported for the supervisord process itself. And instead of all that sed'ing, why not use `supervisorctl pid gunicorn | xargs ...` ?!

Comment: pid = Get the PID of supervisord not of the subprocess

Comment: From `supervisorctl help pid`: `pid <name>              Get the PID of a single child process by name.`

(Which a quick test verifies). Without the name it's `supervisorctl`'s PID.

Comment: @Julian I disagree. I've just tested it `$ sudo supervisorctl pid program1`, `$ sudo supervisorctl pid program2`, `$ sudo supervisorctl pid program3`, and I get every time the same number. Perhaps it has changed in newer versions (I'm using 3.0a8)

Comment: At least on supervisor 3.0, `sudo supervisorctl pid gunicorn` does indeed return the main gunicorn (not supervisord) pid. So then you can run `sudo kill -HUP \`sudo supervisorctl pid gunicorn\`` to gracefully restart Gunicorn. However note that this doesn't necessarily mean zero issues during deployment, because the old workers stop taking requests and your new workers Python app takes some time to boot up, you'll get hanging requests while the new workers get started.

Comment: How does -HUP differ from `supervisorctl reload`?

Comment: @ScottStafford, `supervisorctl reload` asks the supervisor daemon to reload its config. Perhaps you meant `supervisorctl restart`? This is just shorthand for stop followed by start, so the gunicorn master and all workers are clobbered. Using `SIGHUP` leaves the gunicorn master running; new workers are created, old ones gracefully killed. No requests are dropped. Much cleaner.

Comment: just an easier version when using supervisor: `supervisorctl pid NAME | xargs kill -HUP`

Comment: `supervisorctl signal HUP NAME` should also do the trick. http://supervisord.org/running.html#signals

Answer (score 37):

For those not using supervisord: what Rob said, it works with ps as well,

```
ps aux |grep gunicorn |grep projectname | awk '{ print $2 }' |xargs kill -HUP
```

Comment: What would be the difference between these:
$ ps -A | grep gunicorn | awk '{print $1}' | xargs \\\
$ "15135 15189 15193 15196" \\\
$ ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep staging | awk '{print $2}' \\\
$ "15193 15196" \\\

obviously, your version is not picking up all of the gunicorn processes. Only resetting your version worked fine. But what are these other two processes?

Answer (score 17):

### Systemd, gunicorn & Ubuntu

Here is the one-liner, if you are running your gunicorn service with **systemd**.

```
systemctl status gunicorn |  sed -n 's/.*Main PID: \(.*\)$/\1/g p' | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs kill -HUP
```

---

### Details step by step

Since the [gunicorn docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-reload-my-application-in-gunicorn) tell that the correct way to gracefully reload the workers is by using `kill -HUP <Main PID>`, where `<Main PID>` is the process id of the master process, we extract the master PID using systemctl, and run `kill -HUP <Main PID>`.

#### 1) Get info about the process from systemd using the name of the service

```
systemctl status gunicorn
```

where `gunicorn` is the name of the service, located at `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Example output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-4-12-247:~$ systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn server for yourproject.com
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-11-04 19:16:24 UTC; 1h 15min ago
 Main PID: 10673 (gunicorn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─10673 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/tmp/yourproject.socket config.wsgi:application
           ├─11069 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/tmp/yourproject.socket config.wsgi:application
           ├─11070 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/tmp/yourproject.socket config.wsgi:application
           └─11071 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/site/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/tmp/yourproject.socket config.wsgi:application

Nov 04 20:27:04 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:27:04 +0000] [11047] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11047
Nov 04 20:27:04 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:27:04 +0000] [11048] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11048
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [10673] [INFO] Handling signal: hup
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [10673] [INFO] Hang up: Master
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [11046] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11046)
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [11047] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11047)
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [11048] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11048)
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [11069] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11069
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [11070] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11070
Nov 04 20:32:16 ip-10-4-12-247 gunicorn[10673]: [2017-11-04 20:32:16 +0000] [11071] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11071
```

#### 2) Get the process ID (PID) of the main gunicorn process

The **[sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/sed.1.html)** command works like follows:  `sed 's/<search this>/<replace with this>/g'`

- `s` means for the *substitute* command, and `g` means that search the whole input *globally*.
- The `-n` flag tells sed *not* to print every line (or actually, not to print anything.)
- The `p` at the end tells sed to *print the matched line*.
- We search for `.*Main PID: \(.*\)$`, which is a regular expression pattern, which has following parts: `.*` matches any character (`.`) zero or more times (`*`). Then we search for `Main PID:` followed by any characters, repeated zero or more times (`.*`). To capture all characters after the `Main PID:`-text, we enclose the `.*` into parenthesis, which are escaped with backslashes: `\(.*\)`. `$` indicates line end.
- The "replace with this" part of the sed command is just `\1`, which means the first captured set of characters.

Example output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-4-12-247:~$ systemctl status gunicorn |  sed -n 's/.*Main PID: \(.*\)$/\1/g p'
10673 (gunicorn)
```

#### 3) Get rid of the extra characters

Pipe the output to [cut](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/cut.1posix.html). The `cut -f1 -d' '` means, that

- The string is space delimited: Here `-d` determines the delimiter, which is the characted just after the `-d`. Since the delimiter is space, we enclose that in quotes.
- `-f` means just that cutting is made using the delimiter (and not by bytes), and `-f1` means that we want to take out the first element of the list.

Example output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-4-12-247:~$ systemctl status gunicorn |  sed -n 's/.*Main PID: \(.*\)$/\1/g p' | cut -f1 -d' '
10673
```

#### 4) Use the Main PID

Piping to [xargs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/xargs.1posix.html) means just running the command with arguments from the pipe on the left hand side. Since we are piping just the Main PID to xargs,

```
 systemctl status gunicorn-django |  sed -n 's/.*Main PID: \(.*\)$/\1/g p' | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs kill -HUP
```

is basically just the same thing as

```
echo <Main PID > | xargs kill -HUP
```

which translates into

```
kill -HUP <Main PID >
```

---

#### Edit

A little more robust solution would be to use `cut -f1 -d$'\n'` or `grep -m1 ""` in front of `cut -f1 -d' '`, to pick just the first line of the match. I can't figure out any circumstances, where there would be two matches for the `Main PID:`, though.

Comment: `Unit gunicorn.service could not be found.` while I have installed `gunicorn` via `pip`.

Comment: Uhm, you can just ask systemd nicely for the PID: `systemctl show gunicorn -p MainPID --value`. A One-liner would be: `kill -HUP $(systemctl show gunicorn -p MainPID --value)`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe not a direct answer to the question, but for those who are just looking for a way to restart `gunicorn` web server, you can use `killall gunicorn` and then execute a command to start gunicorn again. For example:

```
killall gunicorn
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --reload app:app
```

**Note:** `killall gunicorn` will terminate all gunicorn processes immediately  so make sure you understand what you are doing.

Comment: While that will work, it’s likely bad practice. Reloading gunicorn gracefully will allow active connections to finish as they should. Just killing things will break those connections and if something is left open And gunicorn ain’t there to say close it, you could get into some lame issues. However, If your site/project/constraints are simple enough this is fine to me, sure.

Comment: `killall` can send HUP as well. Just run `killall -s HUP gunicorn`.

Answer (score 6):

We run Gunicorn under Supervisor, but this is the simplest, cleanest way we've found to gracefully reload Gunicorn when it gets confused:

```
sudo pkill -HUP -f gunicorn.*master
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will also give users hitting the web server (nginx) a 500, because Gunicorn is still restarting

Answer (score 1):

If you are running **`gunicorn` on a port** rather than a socket, you can
find the process id (pid) of gunicorn using fuser command. Then **force gunicorn to reload the code** by **sending a `HUP` signal**.

The command `fuser 8000/tcp` will list the process ids of all processes using tcp port 8000.

`fuser -k 8000/tcp` will kill those processes gracelessly which is not recommended.

- `fuser -k -HUP 8000/tcp` will force gunicorn using tcp port 8000 to
  reload the code by sending HUP signal.

Answer (score 1):

When using systemd

calling:

```
systemctl restart gunicorn
```

resulted in 502 bad gateway errors for us. Digging into the nginx logs we saw that the socket file was not found. Calling

```
systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
```

after restarting gunicorn, restarted the socket and brought the server back online.

Answer (score 1):

You can start gunicorn with the code:

```
gunicorn  --pid /var/run/gunicorn.pid --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --reload myproject.asgi.application
```

And graceful restart with the code:

```
cat /var/run/gunicorn.pid | xargs kill -HUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart gunicorn service using cmd
`systemctl restart gunicorn`

else restart gunicorn service and create the sock file again.

Answer (score 0):

Modern and easier way to handle the reload with systemd:

Add the `ExecReload=` directive to the unit file:

```
[Service]
ExecReload=kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

Now you can simply use `sudo systemctl reload unit`.

Answer (score -1):

This can help when gunicorn restart(in a dev/test env) takes a lot of time to restart.

The below command kills the workers.

```
$ sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -n -i | grep gunicorn | awk '{print $2}'`

$ sudo service gunicorn restart
```