# When deploying, do I need FTP? Or just git clone will do the job?

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, ftp

as the question probably implies, I'm a noob, I finished writing my first app and I want to deploy it. I purchased server from digital ocean connected with ssh key. I downloaded nginx and gunicorn, then configured them. I git clone my project I saved in github. Then what? I saw how ftp is used for transfering files but my files are already cloned....I'm not sure how I should deploy it. I'm just following a tutorial like a machine...It's kinda hard to explain. Can someone please help me understand this?>

Comment: neither will help on their own since you need to use something to actually manage your project on the server (i.e apache/nginx etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment is its own art and science, but I'll attempt to answer your questions to get you started.

In the end of the day, FTP and Git are just pulling files into your server. As you can see there are many more solutions to accomplish the same thing. So no, FTP is not required for deployment (neither is Git for that matter).

Other than that I'd like to point out that pulling the source code isn't enough for deployment: you still need to (re)start your services. For you, I believe it is gunicorn-based.

So to sum, at your stage, perhaps you can define "deployment" as two things at least: getting the updated source code into the server and (re)starting the services.

You already did the Git part, so here's an [answer to reload gunicorn after a git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881819/a-better-way-to-restart-reload-gunicorn-via-upstart-after-git-pulling-my-dja)

Answer (score 0):

Use git. Here's a good tutorial for beginning, commit and push.

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/