In flask/gunicorn, how can I set auto-reload info every minute/hour?
I have a EC2-linux server running a simple flask/gunicorn/nginx program that returns a .csv or .JSON file. Another python script runs every hour and updates this .csv with information.
The problem is that changing that .csv does not automatically reload the app.py file (which reads the csv) adn returns the request. Whenever I open the app.py and save it again, script reloads and gets the correct updated info on 'File.csv'.
How can I get the script to auto reload or update? If I could make a cronjob to open file and save without changes every hour, I think it would reload the info that I need.
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import pandas as pd

#
bd =pd.read_csv('File.csv')
A = (bd['A'][0])
B = (bd['B'][0]) 
print(A,B)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_user():
    user_data = {'A':str(A),'B':'+'+str(B) 
}
    
    return jsonify(user_data),200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0',port=8000)


I think this question should be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881819/a-better-way-to-restart-reload-gunicorn-via-upstart-after-git-pulling-my-dja
Basically you need to set up a cronjob that sends the HUP signal to gunicorn to gracefully reload the workers.

Why don't you just read the CSV inside get_user() function so it is always the latest?

That was so simple yet so effective! Thank you so much.

You can write it up as an answer to show other readers what you did, and then accept your own answer. Well done, good luck!

As mentioned in the comments, simply moving the commands to open the .csv file  inside the function guarantees updating the information.
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import pandas as pd

#


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_user():
    bd =pd.read_csv('File.csv')
    A = (bd['A'][0])
    B = (bd['B'][0]) 
    print(A,B)
    user_data = {'A':str(A),'B':'+'+str(B)}
    
    return jsonify(user_data),200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0',port=8000)

